# Continue Fill for Background Image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, responsive-design

I have an image I'm using as background which is 3000px by 1500px.  For responsive design, I need to extend it to 3000 x 3500.  It is an image of a river, and I want to continue the look of the river as seamless as is possible.  I've tried copy and re-pasting parts of it but you can see the repeating pattern.  I've also tried the Clone Stamp tool, but that didn't help much.

[image]

Comment: It really just takes care and practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps attempt using content aware fill. Select the area you wish to fill using the box marquee tool, and then go to Edit > Fill > Content Aware. PhotoShop will fill the area with it's best guess as to what it should be using the rest of the photo. You will more than likely need to do some major retouching, but this should help. If this does not work, try to Patch tool. It is a quick and smart way to fill areas like that.

Answer (score 0):

## Don’t

It's going to look weird no matter what you do, and the file size will be huge. Do a little normalization along the bottom edge (make the texture smooth) so you're not trying to match a naturalistic pattern, then extend the color with a CSS background in your design.

One thing to watch out for is a discrepancy between the jpg color and the browser's CSS color. Color profile disagreements can take the photo one direction and the CSS another.